# How to treat DTC (device tree compiler) warnings as errors in Yocto?

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, device-tree

I noticed that Yocto doesn't show dtc (device tree compiler) warnings at all. Is there any way to treat warnings as errors for example?

I tried different flags such as `-Werror` and `-Wall` but they didn't work. I can only see the warnings when using devshell.

Comment: device tree compilation is visibly handled by devicetree.bbclass which calls itself the dtc compiler with overridable options like DTC_FLAGS.
However, taking a look at dtc command help, it seems there is no option to make warning as error.
In all cases, you need to check if it's possible to do that as Yocto is not supposed to parse process log (unless you do it yourself) to detect warning but to stop a build on a subprocess error code return.